# Is there a command to get latest build number from Firebase App Distribution just like TestFlight latest_testflight_build_number?

Tags: ios, firebase, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

[latest_testflight_build_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/latest_testflight_build_number/#latest_testflight_build_number) allows easy build number bump

example

```
increment_build_number({
  build_number: latest_testflight_build_number + 1
})
```

Is there something similar for Firebase App Distribution?
For example, I've uploaded a build `v1.0.0(130)`
While pushing a new build to Firebase App Distribution, I want to have build number as `v1.0.0(131)`

Comment: Is there any updates about this question? I also would like to have latest Firebase distribution build number.

Comment: +1, It would be great to have this command. @Lucky_girl you can watch for issue on Github https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution/issues/25

Answer (score 2):

As Alexander pointed out, it seems that a new action has been created `firebase_app_distribution_get_latest_release` that does the trick.

Reference at [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution/issues/25) Github issue.